# mutli_select - select2 - repopulate field values

Tags: yadcf

I am using datatables 1.10.x, yadcf 0.9.2(beta), select2 4.0.1.

I have this weird problem, that all of my default multi_select fields (select2) aren't repopulated after a page refresh by default. (stateSave)

When I try to recreate it on JSFiddle it works absolutely perfect. 
When I use costum data to match my mData changes it works superb aswell.

Only the default one without any changes at all does not repopulate the field value. The filter is set and does work:

**Before refresh:**

[image: before refresh]

**After refresh:**

[image: after refresh]

Comment: are you working on local server or you trying to access your html from file system etc' `file:///C:` ?

Comment: I am working on a local server. Live: IIS  Test: IIS-Express

Comment: Something similar is happening to me, stateSave retains the filtered values but won't show up in the column.

Comment: @JaimeArroyoGarcia , then please provide a reproducible test page